# When is the Coen brothers' "The Ladykillers" set?

Tags: the-ladykillers

When do the events of the movie [*The Ladykillers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ladykillers_(2004_film)) (2004) take place?

Comment: I don't think this is stated in the movie. A rough guess could be made based on cultural references though. Post 1983 due to the reference to a Leatherman tool which was not available until then.

Comment: @Paulie_D Post 1993 because, after Garth loses his finger, Gawain talks about what seems to be Bobbit's case: "It's like that dude whose wife cut his dick off threw it on the freeway?" Gawain says also: "I saw the muthafucka in a porno!" so one can get even after 1993 if finds in which year such porno was released

Comment: It's starting to sound like many movies, set in "contemporary without explicit reference". You end up dating these by car models as often as not, though I don't think I've seen this one… perhaps I should, the original was fabulous… though perhaps that's why I never did watch it...